# Change color for any element on page

Tags: css

How do I achieve something like this:

```
*:hover{
    background-color:lightblue;
}
```

I am trying to change background color of any element on the page when hovering on the element. Not sure why it doesnt work.

Comment: its because of specificity.

Comment: how can i make that happen? what is the solution?

Comment: It does work http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/9pta8vbz/

Comment: It will work as long as you don't have any more specific hover background rules in your CSS. Also note that this is horrible for performance, especially if the page has a lot of elements on it.

Comment: @JuanMendes It changes the entire page. I want only that element to change background.

Comment: @StephanMuller I also added "Important" :  background-color:lightblue !important;

Comment: Please define "doesn't work" then.

Comment: @user3311522 My answer explains why it highlights the background, it's because your mouse is hovering over the background also

Comment: @JuanMendes I see. then what is the best way to get only the toppest element to highlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/9pta8vbz/

The problem is that it's highlighting the entire body since the mouse is over the body, so you don't see highlighting on children any differently.

The following example should clarify it http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/9pta8vbz/1/ It will highlight items inside the body

CSS

```
body *:hover{
    background-color:lightblue;
}
```

HTML

```
<p>1 <span>inside</span></p><p>2</p><p>3</p>
```

It will highlight the paragraphs, but the span will behave the same way since the paragraph will also be highlighted

What you are doing cannot be done with CSS alone, you can use JS to add a CSS class to the element that the mouse is over http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/9pta8vbz/2/

CSS

```
.highlight {
    background-color:lightblue;
}
```

JavaScript

```
// This is a simplified version that doesn't take care of edge cases
// known bugs: should use addEventListener, should not wipe out existing `className`,
// e.target is not 100% cross browser, but those are other topics
document.onmouseover = function(e) {
    e.target.className = 'highlight';
}

document.onmouseout = function(e) {
    e.target.className = '';
}
```